# CRUD Architecture design - deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, architecture

I have a Java application to do CRUD operations on Product objects.
The architecture is :

> ProductRepository -> database communication
>
> ProductService -> business logic
>
> ProductController -> API Routes
>
> ProductDeserializer -> Create new Product from API object
>
> ProductSerializer -> Create API object from Product

The creation of a product flow goes :

> API -> ProductController -> ProductDeserializer -> ProductService -> ProductRepository

The method create in the ProductService looks like :

1)

```
public Product create(Product product) {
   validateInput(product);
   Product newProduct = new Product();
   copy(product, newProduct);
   loadBrand(newProduct);
   return productRepository.save(newProduct);
}
```

The question is: is it simpler and better to just do :

2)

```
public Product create(Product product) {
   validateInput(product);
   cleanupBrand(product);
   loadBrand(product);
   return productRepository.save(product);
}
```

Arguments for 1):

- It's the responsibility of the Service to create the Product, not the Deserializer

Arguments for 2):

- The responsibilities are shared, the Deserializer ensures the format, the Service adds business logic and validation.
- Does a car factory that is given the parts to assemble rebuild and remolds all the parts ? No, it just validates them and assemble them.

This example is simplified, but if I have to develop the copy function for the Product it will take some time to code and to maintain, and seems to repeat the work done in the deserializer.

Comment: I don't think argument for 1. is valid. The service has no responsibility in creating the product, the client of your API already did, the service has the responsibility to validate and save (through a repository) the product. Also, a deserializer shouldn't get too much attention because it's only used to conveniently work with data.

Comment: I had thought of the responsibility of the client of the API and forgot to mention it, thanks @ÁkosRatku

Answer (score 1):

If you are just making another copy of SAME Product, I don't see any use / advantage you would be getting by creating a separate copy and then saving that copy. The validation itself should be fine and so #2 looks good.

The only reason I see for doing #1 is when you have a different Service object and that is getting processed some way before getting saved (may be based on caller being a mobile device vs desktop browser etc). In that case the product that got deserailzed would be different from one getting save and you might want to do copy.

Comment: You are right @Guanxi , it's more complicated than what I first said. I edited the question and added as an example loadBrand for the Brand of the Product. The Brand has to be reloaded. In case of a new fresh Product copy it's enough to do a loadBrand but in case we reuse the deserialized object we need to do some cleanup.